# How does the paging concept work with heap and stack memory?

Tags: linux-kernel, memory, memory-management

Does the process pre-allocate heap and stack memory while dividing it into pages?
If yes, will all those pages be empty initially?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Processes (or the kernel, acting on behalf of processes) pre-allocate *address space*, not pages. When a process allocates memory, the corresponding page-table entries are allocated, and [initialised to point to the zero page](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.2/source/mm/memory.c#L3127) (except on architectures which forbid this). The zero page is set up to return all zeroes on reads, and fault on writes — the fault handler will then allocate a separate physical page.

Comment: tnx @Stephen, Page map table should have entry as equal to no of pages in the process right? or page map table will grow dynamically?

Comment: Ah right, you’re interested in the PTE allocation; I’ve updated my answer to address that.

Comment: tnx @Stephen, Now I can understand. Just curious to know "The zero page is set up to return all zeroes on reads" read also should cause page fault right?

Comment: No, because as long as you haven’t written to the page, reads should return zero, so there’s no need to handle reads specially.

Comment: ohh nice, how CPU finds page is still not written, is there any additional bit stored in page table?

Comment: The zero page is mapped read-only. Any attempted writes cause a page fault; the kernel then maps in a different page, updates the PTE, and restarts the write to the new page, and subsequent reads come from the new page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104167/discussion-between-karthik-nedunchezhiyan-and-stephen-kitt).